# Why creating a thread inside an unique_ptr makes the thread destruct?

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple function that flushes to a file in a thread, so it does not block the main thread:

```
void MultiChannelDiskRecordingWav::flush() {
    size_t amountToWrite = mWriteCursorFrames*mChannelCount;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < amountToWrite; i++) {
        tempWriteBuffer[i] = writeBuffer[i];
    }


    auto flush = [this, capturedWriteCursorFrames = mWriteCursorFrames, capturedChannelCount = mChannelCount](){
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lk{recordingFileMutex};
            std::vector<float> floats(tempWriteBuffer, tempWriteBuffer + mWriteCursorFrames*mChannelCount);
            recordingFile.Write(floats);
            bytesWritten += capturedWriteCursorFrames*capturedChannelCount*sizeof(float);
        }
    };

    flushThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(flush);
}
```

I'm getting a crash with these functions in the backtrace:

```
(_ZSt9terminatev+52)
(_ZNSt6__ndk16threadD1Ev+24)
(_ZN28MultiChannelDiskRecordingWav5flushEv+268)
```

which translate to

```
(std::terminate() 52)
(std::__ndk1::thread::~thread() 24)
(MultiChannelDiskRecordingWav::flush() 268)
```

Why is the thread being deleted? I'm not moving it, I'm creating inside an `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Where do you do the `flushThread->join();`?

Comment: @Eljay on `~MultiChannelDiskRecordingWav`

Comment: Do you call `flush` more than once?  If so, do you `flushThread->join();` before reassigning to flushThread a new thread?

Comment: @Eljay indeed it's on the second call that it crashes. Even though there was enough time for the latest flush to finish, it still crashes. Doing join worked. Why do I have to join, even if the thread ended?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs [Documentation is your friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread)

Comment: What is `flushThread`? Create a [mcve]

Comment: I bet the `flushThread` variable *already has a thread in it* and *that one* is being destructed.

Comment: *Why do I have to join, even if the thread ended?* Because it is waiting to be joined before it can expire.  (Or detached, but that's a whole 'nother can of worms you don't want to tangle with.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```cpp
flushThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(flush);
```

You are creating a new `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>` and assigning it to an existing `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>` named `flushThread`.  When `flushThread` is assigned to, it will destroy any `std::thread` that it already holds.  It is that existing `std::thread` that is being destroyed, not the new `std::thread` that you just created.

When a `std::thread` object is destroyed, its destructor will call `std::terminate()` if the thread is `joinable()`.  So, you will have to do something like this to ensure that the existing thread is finished before you create the new thred:

```cpp
if (flushThread) flushThread->join(); // <-- add this
flushThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(flush);
```